# Is $U_8$ isomorphic to $K_4$ (Klein Group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

$U_8=\{1,3,5,7\}$ since this group has one element of order one, three elements of two order and no element of $4$ order .. so does the Klein group.

Both $U_8$ and the Klein group are non cyclic groups whose every proper subgroup is cyclic, so the Klein group is isomorphic to U(8)?

Comment: is this the isomorphism defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZTuj.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZTuj.jpg)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677437/show-u8-is-isomorphic-to-the-group-of-matrices/1677456#1677456), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117941/isomorphism-between-u-10-u-8-u-5/117946#117946).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There are only two groups of order four](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_4): (1) the cyclic group and (2) the Klein group.

As all elements of $U(8)$ are of order $2$, $U(8)$ is indeed isomorphic as a group to the Klein group.

**The key argument is that there is no other groups of order four than the two mentioned above.**

Comment: hey can u help finding all proper subgroups of Z2 × Z2 × Z2 ? i want to know how to approach to such problems ..any methodol

Comment: I suggest you post another question to avoid mixing different topics.